# warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: c, gcc

Please Help me to identify the problem with the Function pointer for the menu items is giving the error "initialization from incompatible pointer type"

This is header file

```
/**
 * Represents a function that can be selected from the list of
 * menu_functions - creates a new type called a menu_function.
 */
void displayItems(VmSystem * system);
typedef void (*MenuFunction)(VmSystem *);


/**
 * Represents a menu item to be displayed and executed in the program.
 **/
typedef struct menu_item
{
    char text[MENU_NAME_LEN + NULL_SPACE];
    MenuFunction function;
} MenuItem;

void initMenu(MenuItem * menu);
MenuFunction getMenuChoice(MenuItem * menu);


MenuItem menu[NUM_MENU_ITEMS];
```

main menu file

```
typedef enum boolean
{
    FALSE = 0,
    TRUE
} Boolean;

void initMenu(MenuItem * menu)
{
    /* Strings names of menu items */
    char * menu_items[] = {
        "Display Items",
        "Purchase Items",
        "Save and Exit",
        "Add Item",
        "Remove Item",
        "Display Coins",
        "Reset Stock",
        "Reset Coins",
        "Abort Program"
    };
```

Function pointer for the menu items

```
    Boolean(*MenuFunction[])(VmSystem *) = {
        displayItems,  /*Here i got the error */
        purchaseItem,
        saveStock,
        addItem,
        removeItem,
        displayCoins,
        resetStock,
        resetCoins,
        abortProgram
    };
```

Comment: What is e.g. `displayItems`? Is it matching the type-alias `MenuFunction`? What is `Boolean`? Is it equal to `void` (which is the return type of `MenuFunction` functions)?

Comment: Please ensure that you've provided a [mcve] in your question!

Comment: displayItems and all others items void displayItems(VmSystem * system) , Boolean is enum  , and menu function is : typedef void (*MenuFunction)(VmSystem *);

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please don't use your own boolean types. C has had [a boolean type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean) since C99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

The first:

```
typedef void (*MenuFunction)(VmSystem *);
```

followed by

```
Boolean(*MenuFunction[])(VmSystem *) = { ... };
```

Two different things, same name.

Then as for your errors: You state in a comment that e.g. `displayItem` matches the function type `MenuFunction`, and that it returns `void`. The problem is that the array `MenuFunction` (see how confusing this can be?) is an array of function returning `Boolean`. The two types are not compatible, and you must change one.

Comment: Thanks alot You save my day , i almost spend 2 hours on it , newbie :)